# Rendering form for new associated object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble with creating association;

My models are Table and Columns (one table to many columns).

In my ColumnsController:

```
def new
    @table = Table.find(params[:id])
    @column = @table.columns.build
end
```

In my app/views/tables/show.html.erb:

```
<%= @table.name %></dd>
<%= render "columns/form" %>
```

In my app/views/columns/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for  @column, :url => {:action => :create, :id => @table.id }do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name  %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.button :submit%><% end %>
```

When I run it:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #1):
<%= form_for  @column, :url => {:action => :create, :id => @table.id } do |f| %>
```

Why ? :-(

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it with partials and local variables:

```
<%= render partial: "columns/form", locals: {table: @table, column: @column} %>
```

and

```
<%= form_for  column, :url => {:action => :create, :id => table.id }do |f| %>
```

If you want it even simpler, you can do this:

```
<%= render partial: "columns/form", locals: {table: @table} %>
```

and

```
<%= form_for table.columns.new do |f| %>
```

Comment: @David Can you paste your table.rb please?

Comment: class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :columns
  has_many :helps, as: :helpable
  has_many :titles, as: :titleable
  has_many :functions, as: :funcable
end   ... Thanks, @PeterSmith

Comment: The only explanation I can provide is that your `@table` is nil... I can't make anything else of it, sorry... and... who is Peter Smith??

Comment: Sorry for Peter Smith, I understood mistakenly that it's your name.. I believe the problem is bad routes. I`ll check it again. Thanks.